# Is it possible, in R, to access the values of a list with a for loop on the names of the fields?

Tags: json, r

I have a big json file, containing 18 fields, some of which contain some other subfields. I read the file in R in the following way:

```
    json_file <- "daily_profiles_Bnzai_20150914_20150915_20150914.json"
    data <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=",")))
```

This gives me a giant list with all the fields contained in the json file. I want to make it into a data.frame and do some operations in the meantime. For example if I do:

```
    doc_length <- data.frame(t(apply(as.data.frame(data$doc_lenght_map), 1, unlist)))
    os <- data.frame(t(apply(as.data.frame(data$operating_system), 1, unlist)))
    navigation <- as.data.frame(data$navigation)
    monday <- data.frame(t(apply(navigation[,grep("Monday",names(data$navigation))],1,unlist)))
    Monday <- data.frame(apply(monday, 1, sum))
```

works fine, I get what I want, with all the right subfields and then I want to join them in a final data.frame that I will use to do other operations.
Now, I'd like to do something like that on the subset of fields where I don't need to do operations. So, for example, the days of the week contained in navigation are not included. I'd like to have something like (suppose I have a data.frame df):

```
    for(name in names(data))
    {
      df <- cbind(df, data.frame(t(apply(as.data.frame(data$name), 1, unlist)))
    }
```

The above loop gives me errors. So, what I want to do is finding a way to access all the fields of the list in an automatic way, as in the loop, where the iterator "name" takes on all the fields of the list, without having to call them singularly and then doing some operations with those fields. I tried even with

```
    for(name in names(data))
    {
      df <- cbind(df, data.frame(t(apply(as.data.frame(data[name]), 1, unlist)))
    }
```

but it doesn't take all of the subfields. I also tried with

```
    data[, name]
```

but it doesn't work either. So I think I need to use the "$" operator.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank you a lot!

Davide

Comment: I think that you can do what you're trying to do with an apply function, more specifically lapply, but without knowing _exactly_ what you're trying to do I can't be of any further help.  Can you modify your question to include an example?

Comment: Did you try `x <- data[,name]` as well? And as the previous commenter said, you can probably do this more efficiently with some version of `apply` run over the vector of variable names.

Comment: Thank you, I modified it, I hope you can understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other commenters, I am confused, but I will throw this out to see if it might point you in the right direction.

```
# make mtcars a list as an example
data <- lapply(mtcars,identity)

do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    names(data),
    function(name){
      data.frame(data[name])
    }
  )
)
```